# Alsamixer settings reset everytime headphones are plugged in/unplugged

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm on KDE Neon using Kernel 5.15.0-70-generic.

I recently started experiencing a problem where every time I unplug or plug in headphones, my settings in alsamixer reset to some point in the past. This disables auto mute mode and sets the volume of my sound card to 74.

I don't believe it's pulseaudio or pipewire, as I recently replaced pulseaudio with pipewire. This did solve the volume issue, however it still seems like no matter what I cannot get auto mute mode to stay enabled.

I've tried using `alsactl store` to save the settings I want, as well as setting `amixer sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Enabled` on boot in `~/.profile`.

I believe the problem may be me needing to use a slightly older version of the kernel due to issues for me in 5.19, because this is when started these issues, but I can't be sure. I also cannot test this because audio doesn't work in 5.19 for me.

Comment: I have almost exactly this problem! Unplugging or plugging in headphones sets my master volume to level 73, disables auto-mute, and sets the internal mic boost to 20 dB gain (level 53). I've been going through the configuration files in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths`, zeroing out more and more mic boost elements, but the behavior doesn't change.